# Error in Forwarder creation in MultiSig Wallet

Tags: solidity, remix, multisignature

The following code,

```
function createForwarder() public returns (address) {
   return new Forwarder();
}
```

gives error,

```
TypeError: Return argument type contract Forwarder is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) address.
return new Forwarder();
```

Currently I am using pragma solidity version ^0.5.1, how can I solve this particular error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option #1: Change `new Forwarder()` to `address(new Forwarder())`.

Option #2: Change `returns (address)` to `returns (Forwarder)`.

I'd go with #1 (to be honest, I've tried #2 only with interfaces).